# POST for Azure Mobile/Web App (working from Arduino)

Tags: azure, post, arduino, iot, azure-mobile-services

I want to find samples of how to work with Mobile/Web App by sending POST.
Previously in Mobile Services it was possible to send POST like this:

```
POST /tables/table_name HTTP/1.1
Host: http://arduinounoserver.azure-mobile.net/
X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: YaRWxxxxzKGRxxxxLPiNxxxxXYOvxxxx
{"value": 234}
```

But now authentication was absolutely changed.
How to do it now and is it possible to find somewhere POST samples?

Have found only [Table Service REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179423.aspx) but it's still not clear for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can still use next URL notation to access tables:

```
https://yoursite/tables/tablename
```

but, you can get an error:

```
{"error":"An invalid API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of 2.0.0."}
```

so with Web App Easy Table you should use next ZUMO-header, for example

```
POST https://vyutest.azurewebsites.net/Tables/Test HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json 
Content-Length: 49 
ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0 
Host: vyutest.azurewebsites.net

{"text":"Complete the tutorial","complete":false}
```

It works.

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir! And what is about authentification? That would be great iot sample.

Comment: For IoT, it's general that the IoT device uses IoTHub or EventHubs to inject data into the system - that's custom made for the device side.  Then you look at the data with a mobile or web client - there are demos on user authentication for the various devices in samples and on the azure.com website.

Comment: Have found [this link](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/doncoleman/mkr1000-temp-and-humidity-sensor-8f22ed?ref=platform&ref_id=424_recent___&offset=31) about Arduino and Azure direct connection. Thanks, @AdrianHall, your recommendation was also very helpful

Comment: As I have understand to send POST message for Azure Mobile/Web app is possible, but it's not recommended way.